# Toggling between status on model with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### The scenario

There is a table on my database called `budgets`. It has `author_id`, `status`, `answered_at` columns.

### The goal

When `status != 1`, then `author_id` and `answered_at` should be `nil`/`null`.

### The problem

I have the following method on my `budgets_controller.rb`:

```
def update
  budget = Budget.find(params[:id])
  budget.update_attributes(status: 1, author_id: current_user.id, answered_at: DateTime.now.to_date)

  budget.save!
end
```

I want to know if is possible to reuse the same method (`update`) to change the `author_id` and the `answered_at` to null and the `status` itself to `0` if it is *already* `1`. Some kind of `toggle`.

### Knowledge

I saw Rails offers [this method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle!) to toggling boolean values, but I can't see how it can suit my need since I'm working with two other columns which aren't booleans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you probably want is a [model callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).  In your instance, something like

```
# on models/budget.rb

before_update :nullify_author

def nullify_author
  if status == 1
    author = nil
    answered_at = nil
    status = 0
    save
  end
end
```

Also, you shouldn't use `toggle` here.  Ruby's falsiness is WAY more restrictive than JavaScript's.  In Ruby's case, only `false` and `nil` are falsy.  Relevantly to you, 0 is *not* falsy but truthy.  To prove it, try `!0`.  The returned value is the boolean `false` not the FixNum 1

Comment: I liked your approach. Very creative! Thank you! :P

Comment: I'm going back and forth on whether it should be a before or after update, but the important part is putting this logic in the model, NOT the controller.